# error:’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c

I have a header file named store.h which contains a struct and my main is located in E.c,i am currently experiencing an error which i can not comprehend why it is happening. Any help is much appreciated

store.h:

```
struct st{
    char *buf,*var;
    int line_number;
    char *keywords;
    char *operators;
};
```

E.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "store.h"
#define max 1000000
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    FILE *fp;
    int ag=0;
    
    fp=fopen( argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("error cannot open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }                                  

    while(feof(fp)==0){  
        *buf=fgets(*buf,max,fp);
    
    // irrelevant commands follow
    
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

On the line `*buf=fgets(*buf,max,fp);` I get the `error:‘buf’ undeclared (first use in this function)`, however I have declared it in my struct and I have included the file that contains the struct, where am I wrong?

Comment: `buf` is a member of structure. So it needs to be accessed as a member of a structure.

Comment: oh i see, thanks for the explanation, much appreciated

Comment: I'd say the error you get is because you need to go back to your beginners book, tutorial or class and read more. Not only about structures and how to handle them, but also on basic I/O like how the [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) function really works.

Comment: Ensure that you allocate a sufficient amount of memory before taking the pointers in use. Otherwise, you'll get a hit from segfault.

Comment: yeah i will most surely have another look on structs and stdio funtions, as i am a beginner.

Comment: please read [why is while(!feof(f) always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("error cannot open file\n");`  error messages should be output to `stderr`,not `stdout`  When the error is from a C library function, should also output to `stderr` the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );` as that function is made for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

1. `buf` is a member of the struct.
2. You need to define the struct object.
3. You need to allocate memory for `buf`.
4. You should not assign `buf` with return value as it may cause a memory leak
5. [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    FILE *fp;
    struct st s;
    int ag=0;

    s.buf = malloc(max);
    if(!s.buf) exit(2);
    fp=fopen( argv[1],"r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("error cannot open file\n");
            exit(1);
    }
                                            

    while(fgets(s.buf,max,fp)){  
         /* ...*/ 
    }
     /* .... */
```